# Python : file.seek(10000000000, 2000000000). Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, file, int

im developing a program that downloads "big files" from the internet (from 200mb to 5Gb) using threads and file.seek to find a offset and insert the data to a main file, but when i try to set the offset above the 2147483647 byte (exceeds the C long max value) it gives the *int too large to convert to C long* error. how can i work around this? Bellow is a representation of my script code.

```
f = open("bigfile.txt")

#create big file
f.seek(5000000000-1)
f.write("\0")

#try to get the offset, this gives the error (Python int too large to convert to C long)
f.seek(3333333333, 4444444444)
```

I wouldn't be asking (because it has been asked a lot) if i really found a solution to this.

I read about casting it to a int64 and use something like UL but i dont really understand it. I hope you can help or at least try make this clearer in my head. xD

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your main problem, but here's a related observation: I don't think seeking and writing to a file would actually "insert" text - rather, I think it would overwrite the existing text at the seek point

Comment: i understand what you mean and its correct. what im trying to do is create a 5gb file with useless data (the size depends on the size of the downloaded file), and then overwrite it with the correct data using file.seek pointing to a specified offset (because the file is downloaded with several threads and i need to write the data in the correct position to that file). I guess i didnt explained myself that well. But thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: Opening a file for writing, seeking a long distance and then writing something allocates almost no space at all on many file systems. The result is a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) which has a long length in its i-node but no actual disk blocks allocated to it. To actually pre-allocate space, you need to write to every block you want allocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f.seek(3333333333, 4444444444)
```

That second argument is supposed to be the `from_where` argument, dictating whether you're seeking from:

- the file start, `os.SEEK_SET` or `0`;
- the current position, `os.SEEK_CUR` or `1`;
- the end of the file, `os.SEEK_END` or `2`.

`4444444444` is *not* one of the allowed values.

The following program works fine:

```
import os
f = open("bigfile.txt",'w')
f.seek(5000000000-1)
f.write("\0")
f.seek(3333333333, os.SEEK_SET)
print f.tell()                   # 'print(f.tell())' for Python3
```

and outputs `3333333333` as expected.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, i guess i didnt really understand the docs, i thought, with seek i could get an offset of data from the file. being the first argument the start and the second the end like (4444444444 - 3333333333) :) :) :)

Comment: @user3754262: pass `os.SEEK_*` constants as the 2nd parameter.